# module initialization error: /var/task/TDNN.dll: invalid ELF header

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, dll

After searching through various resources, mostly from stackoverflow. I am able to get my code working on following python versions on my laptop (with Windows 10 installed)
1. WinPython3.4 64 bit
2. WinPython3.4 32 bit
3. Python 2.7 32 bit and in its virtualenv
4. Python 2.7 64 bit  and in its virtualenv

Then I wanted it to deploy to aws lambda. for that I tried following two options for all above options one by one
1. Just zip .py file for the code and the referenced dll
2. zip .py file for the code and the referenced dll with 3 & 4 virtualenv

But in all these cases I am getting "module initialization error: /var/task/TDNN.dll: invalid ELF header " error message in cloudwatch.

I looked around but i did not find any solution. I would appreciate for any help/pointer. Thnx in advance.

Below is the code

---

```
import json
import urllib
import re
import os, sys
import datetime
import math
from math import *
import csv
import time
#import boto3
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
#s3 = boto3.client('s3')    

NNepochs=50
inputDataL= [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
desiredDataL= [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]
CVInputDataL= [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
CVDesiredDataL= [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]



inputData = (ctypes.c_float * len(inputDataL))(*inputDataL)
desiredData = (ctypes.c_float * len(desiredDataL))(*desiredDataL)
CVInputData = (ctypes.c_float * len(CVInputDataL))(*CVInputDataL)
CVDesiredData = (ctypes.c_float * len(CVDesiredDataL))(*CVDesiredDataL)
outputData = (ctypes.c_float * len(desiredDataL))(*desiredDataL)

## NN starts here
#keytdnndll = 'D:/Documents/1. Vultures Pick/AmazonCloud/QCollector/NIFTY/STP/TDNN/TDNN.dll'
keytdnndll='TDNN.dll'
TDNNdll=ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(keytdnndll)
createNetwork=getattr(TDNNdll,'createNetwork')
#print(createNetwork, callable(createNetwork))
TDNN=ctypes.c_int()
#print('TDNN pointer', TDNN)
createNetwork(ctypes.byref(TDNN),1)
#print('TDNN pointer', TDNN)
resetNetwork=getattr(TDNNdll,'resetNetwork')
resetNetwork(TDNN)
trainNetwork=getattr(TDNNdll,'train')
setCrossValidationEnabled = getattr(TDNNdll,'setCrossValidationEnabled')
getCrossValidationEnabled = getattr(TDNNdll,'getCrossValidationEnabled')
crossValEnabled=ctypes.c_bool()
getCrossValidationEnabled(TDNN, ctypes.byref(crossValEnabled))
print('crossValEnabled',crossValEnabled)
#print(setCrossValidationEnabled, callable(setCrossValidationEnabled))
true=ctypes.c_char()
setCrossValidationEnabled(TDNN, ctypes.byref(true))
getCrossValidationEnabled(TDNN, ctypes.byref(crossValEnabled))
print('crossValEnabled',crossValEnabled)
epochs = ctypes.c_int(NNepochs)
print('epochs', epochs)
dl=len(inputDataL)
datalength = ctypes.c_int(dl)
print('datalength', datalength)
trainNetwork(TDNN,epochs,datalength,inputData,desiredData,datalength,CVInputData,CVDesiredData)
getEpochOfBestCost = getattr(TDNNdll,'getEpochOfBestCost')
epochnumber=ctypes.c_int()
getEpochOfBestCost(TDNN,ctypes.byref(epochnumber))
print('epochnumber', epochnumber)
getNumberOfEpochsTrained=getattr(TDNNdll, 'getNumberOfEpochsTrained')
epochtrained=ctypes.c_int()
getNumberOfEpochsTrained(TDNN,ctypes.byref(epochtrained))
print('epochtrained', epochtrained)
getResponse=getattr(TDNNdll,'getResponse')
getResponse(TDNN,datalength,inputData,outputData)
floatPtr = ctypes.cast(outputData, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
outputDataL = [floatPtr[i] for i in range(dl)]
print('outputDataL', outputDataL)
destroyNetwork=getattr(TDNNdll,'destroyNetwork')
destroyNetwork(TDNN)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

An default AWS machine runs Linux and will not support dlls, which are make for Windows. You have to emulate Windows with wine or find a native Linux solution.

AFAIK Amazon also offers Windows machines which would be an option.

In general you should have a development environment that matches your deployment environment at least at the basics like OS and architecture.

Comment: Thnx Klaus. Do you think DLL has to be rebuilt using Windows within Linux environment or even virtualenv also need to be created using Windows within Linux environment.

Comment: DLLs are a Windows format, they are not designed to run on Linux. The Linux equivalent is a `.so` file. Usually more work than just recompiling is required to convert. A virtual environment should always be recreated on the target system, this also includes the C binaries in some packages.

Comment: Thnx Klaus,I intend to use only Python2.7 available on AWS Lambda plus my DLL. When you say more work need to be done - May I pls request you to list them in order or some reference for those steps. I can write code in one or other language but when it comes to systems or integrating across environments i am a novice. I would be extremely thankful for any of your help.