# aws lambda versus azure functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, dll, lambda, azure-functions

After nearly a month of work I am stuck with aws lamda's underlying execution environment which is Linux and the external DLL that I have to use are written in Windows. And while doing research over internet looks like it will be very difficult to use Windows DLLs with aws lambda. Here is link to my query regarding this issue -[module initialization error: /var/task/TDNN.dll: invalid ELF header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455638/module-initialization-error-var-task-tdnn-dll-invalid-elf-header)

Therefore, I am now considering to move to azure functions assuming that I may not face this limitation over there. So could any one comment about Azure's underlying execution environment like is it windows or linux? I am correct in my conclusion.

Any comment will be highly useful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Azure functions are hosted in a windows machine next to an Azure Website. 
You can easily use an existing dll in your function by adding it by FTP in the function root folder (within a bin folder) and then use #r to reference it from the azure function code.

Here is an example, a dll named "WorkOnImages.dll" is uploaded in an azure in azure function folder : [image]